# Upgrade to rails 4.2.1 from 3.2.22 increased db cpu usage

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4

I upgraded my rails application from rails 3.2.22 to rails 4.2.1. But my database CPU usage has increased drastically. I had to rollback to previous rails version. I am not sure this is a known issue or cache is not working properly or i am missing some configuration. Attaching images from newrelic.

[image: new relic data image 1]

[image: new relic data image 2]

Can anybody give me any idea why this happening. Thanks in advance.